# making countdown as thread

Tags: android, multithreading, button, countdown

I have used this code in Eclipse and it runs perfectly,but when I use the same code in android studio the result error on phone even though no red line appear.Anybody knows how to solve it ?

```
class Allthread extends Thread{                                 

    public void run(){

        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                box2.setText("00:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                box2.setText("Time's Up!");
            }
        };
    }
}

public void buttonOnClick(View view) {
    Allthread T2 = new Allthread();                       
    T2.start();
}
```

Comment: At which line getting as red line? Probably `TextView box2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box2);` one?

Comment: there's no red line in android studio but when I run it in android phone, just one click on button the app become crashes "Unfortunately app has stopped".

Comment: If there's no red line, it means uncaught exception didn't occur on UI thread. I'd check if box2 is null before assigning text to it (a simple if(box2==null) Log.e("ERROR", "box2 is null"); would do it)

Comment: maybe this link will help: don't access UI elements ( like TextView) on [worker threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads)